# JqGrid with autocompletion cant parse data from controller to view

Tags: jqgrid

Last few days i was trying to get jqgrid with autocompletion fields to work, now i can get it to work with local data, but as soon as i trying to get data from  my controller data didnt get parsed.

View code:

```
          { name: 'EanNummer', index: 'EanNummer', width: 65, sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: {
              dataInit:
          function (elem) {
              $(elem).autocomplete({ minLength: 0, source: '@Url.Action("GetBrands")' })
              .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                  return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.Id + ", " + item.Name + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
              };
          } 
          }
          },
```

if instead of source: url i use  source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"] for example code works fine and shows up, so something must be wrong with my controller side code

Controller Code:

```
    public JsonResult GetBrands()
    {

        string vendorId = "";
        var username = "";
        var name = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        var charArray = name.Split("\\".ToCharArray());
        username = charArray.Last();
        vendorId = service.GetVendorIdByUsername(username);

        List<String> list = new List<String>();
        var brands = service.getBrandsByVendor(vendorId);

        var s= (from brand in brands
                     select new
                     {
                         Id = brand.BrandId,
                         Name = brand.BrandName

                     }).ToList();

        return Json(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `item.Id` and `item.Name` on the client side you should return not the `List<String>`. Instead of that you should returns the list of `new {Id=brand.BrandId, Name=brand.BrandName}`. You should just use LINQ instead of `foreach`:

```cs
return Json ((from brand in brands
              select new {
                  Id = brand.BrandId,
                  Name = brand.BrandName
              }).ToList());
```

**UPDATED**: I modified for you the demo from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644) and included jQuery UI Autocomplete support in two forms. The standard rendering:

[image]

and the custom rendering:

[image]

The Autocomplete functionality works in [Advanced Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching) dialog in the same way like in the [Searching Toolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching):

[image]

You can download the demo from [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridDemoVS2010_withAutocomplete.zip).

The server code of the standard autocomplete is

```cs
public JsonResult GetTitleAutocomplete (string term) {
    var context = new HaackOverflowEntities();
    return Json ((from item in context.Questions
                  where item.Title.Contains (term)
                  select item.Title).ToList(),
                 JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

It returns array of strings in JSON format. The list of Titles are filtered by `term` argument which will be initialized to the string typed in the input field.

The server code of the custom autocomplete is

```cs
public JsonResult GetIds (string term) {
    var context = new HaackOverflowEntities();
    return Json ((from item in context.Questions
                  where SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal ?)item.Id).Contains(term) 
                  select new {
                      value = item.Id,
                      //votes = item.Votes,
                      title = item.Title
                  }).ToList (),
                 JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

It uses [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466276.aspx) to be able to use `LIKE` in comparing of the integers. Moreover it returns the list of objects having `value` the `title` property. If you would return objects having `value` the `lable` properties the values from the `lable` properties will be displayed in the Autocomplete context menu and the corresponding `value` property will be inserted in the input field. We use custom `title` property instead.

The code of the client side is

```js
searchoptions: {
    dataInit: function (elem) {
        $(elem).autocomplete({ source: '<%= Url.Action("GetTitleAutocomplete") %>' });
    }
}
```

for the standard rendering and

```js
searchoptions: {
    sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'],
    dataInit: function (elem) {
        // it demonstrates custom item rendering
        $(elem).autocomplete({ source: '<%= Url.Action("GetIds") %>' })
            .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                    .append("<a><span style='display:inline-block;width:60px;'><b>" +
                        item.value + "</b></span>" + item.title + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
            };
    }
}
```

for the custom rendering.

Additionally I use some CSS settings:

```css
.ui-autocomplete {
    /* for IE6 which not support max-height it can be width: 350px; */
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */
    padding-right: 20px;
}
/*.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu { opacity: 0.9; }*/
.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu .ui-menu-item { font-size: 0.75em; }
.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu a.ui-state-hover { border-color: Tomato }
.ui-resizable-handle {
    z-index: inherit !important;
}
```

You can uncomment `.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu { opacity: 0.9; }` setting if you want to have some small 
opacity effect in the autocomplete context menu.

Comment: @Timsen: Sorry, you should use `ToList()` or `ToArray()` which I forgot to include at the beginning.

Comment: Now action get called everytime i am trying to write something in the field, but my list still doesnt shows up

Comment: @Timsen: I see some errors in your code. I have to do other things now, but if your problem will still not solve till the time, I will write you later a demo which demonstrate the usage of `autocomplete` (inclusive custom rendering with `_renderItem`) in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: just cant get it to work... tryed to simplyfie it, to only use name, but it didnt worked either.

Comment: @Timsen: I modified my answer and included [the VS010 demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridDemoVS2010_withAutocomplete.zip) which can be use to "play" with the functionality.

Comment: Works like a charm, i was missing the term part ofcourse, i should have known that, since controller just dont know what to seasrch for..
Thatnk you so much Oleg

Comment: @Timsen: You are welcome! I make minimal modification in the code of the demo. Ij you downloaded it before you can download it one more time.