# jqgrid search mvc3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I am trying to search through a list of dates in my jqgrid using the advanced search toolbar with MVC3 as the platform.

I have got the toolbar to display when I click on the search button in the pager by writing

```
var filters =
{
   "groupOp": "AND",
   "rules": [{ "field": "Date_of_Service", "op": "eq", "data": ""}]
} 

grid3 = $('#BillInformation').jqGrid({
     url: 'CaseInfo/DisplayBillInfoGrid/' + '?caseID=' + caseID,
     ...
     colModel:[
     ...
     { name: 'Date of Service', index: 'Date_of_Service', ... },
     ...
     postData: {
        filters: JSON.stringify(filters)
     },
     ...
});

grid3.navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: false },
        {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true, sFilters: filters }).navButtonAdd('#pager', {
...
});
```

How do I retrieve the data from the search modal dialog that pops up when I click on the search button. I did look at the [Advanced Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching) but when I click on the find button my controller doesn't retrieve the search parameters(ie equal, greater than etc) and the value to be searched.

This is my action method in my controller

```
public ActionResult DisplayBillInfoGrid(string sidx, string sord, int page, 
   int rows, string caseID, string filters)
   {
   ...
   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to get information from the Advanced Search Dialog manually and sen it manually inside of the `postData`. jqGrid do already all this for you. Instead of that you can place `caseID` inside of `postData`.

I recommend you to download [the demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridDemoVS2010.zip) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) or [the demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridDemoVS2010_withAutocomplete.zip) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7392816/315935). The demos includes the implementation of the advanced searching feature.

Comment: Thank you Oleg. As always great advice. I got my controller to retrieve the necessary information