# Firebug errors that I cannot make them disappear

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I keep getting this error in Firebug:
`d is undefined
[Break On This Error] randId:function(d){return(d?d:b.jgrid....(i,d);if(g)return d;return d.length>`

I use JqGrid Version: [4.3.1](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=883)

My controller method looks like this :

```
public JsonResult CategoryList(int page)
    {
        List<CategoryDTO> categories = ServiceUtil.AuctionService.ListCategories();
        List<dynamic> json = new List<dynamic>();

        if (categories != null && categories.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (CategoryDTO cat in categories)
            {
                json.Add(new { Id = cat.Id, Name = cat.Name, Update = cat.LastUpdate, Regex = cat.ValidationXSD });
            }
        }

        var result = new
        {
            total = 1,
            page = page,
            records = categories == null ? 0 : categories.Count,
            rows = (from cat in categories.Take(10)
                    select
                        new { Id = cat.Id, Name = cat.Name, Update = cat.LastUpdate, Regex = cat.ValidationXSD }
                    ).ToArray()
        };

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

The view like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#jqgridListCategory").jqGrid({
        url: '/Admin/ManageCategory/CategoryList',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'LastUpdate', 'RegularExpression'],
        colModel: [{ name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 40, align: 'left' }, { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 400, align: 'left' }, { name: 'LastUpdate', index: 'LastUpdate', width: 40, align: 'left' }, { name: 'RegularExpression', index: 'RegularExpression', width: 40, align: 'left'}],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        sortname: 'Id',
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Categories'
    });
});
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong, any ideas?

Edit 1: Use latest jquery version 1.7.2.

Edit 2: I do not expect Regex from controller to be nothing but a string in View

Comment: Try to use some other jquery version

Comment: What are you using the json variable for?

Comment: In your controller you put Regex and the javascript expect RegularExpression, it's that right?

Comment: I am using that variable to return all the data from jqgrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CategoryList` action produce the data in the wrong format. Either you have to use `jsonReader` or change the code of `CategoryList` action.

[The standard format](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data) of items from the `rows` part of the server response should be like the following

```
{"id" :"1", "cell": ["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]}
```

If the first column `Id` is unique and can be used as the id of the row you can use just array or strings instead:

```
rows = (from cat in categories.Take(10)
        select new[] {
            cat.Id.ToString(),
            cat.Name,
            cat.LastUpdate.ToString(),
            cat.ValidationXSD
        }).ToArray()
```

In the jqGrid you should add `key: true` to the list of the properties of the column 'Id' and add the following jqGrid option

```
jsonReader: { cell: "" }
```

I recommend you to play with [the demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridDemoVS2010.zip) from my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) or with it's [modification](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridDemoVS2010_withAutocomplete.zip) from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7392816/315935).

Comment: @Floradu88: You are welcome! Is the problem which you described in your question still exist after the changes which I suggest in my answer?

Comment: i have to do some changes, to revert some of the changes i did, will accept answer if it works

Comment: @Floradu88: OK, if you will have any problem you can just write here a comment.