# Jqgrid with autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am seeking sample code for adding autocomplete feature to Jqgrid when editing through inline and adding a row using form. Where I tried, got only code to add datepicker.

Comment: Don't expect us to write any code for you. Look on Google, and start coding yourself. It's usually the best way to learn.

Comment: I am new to Jquery and Jqgrid. I have a autocomplete plugin with me but I am not sure about integrating it. And in google I am not able to find perfect working example.

Comment: Search on google for `jquery autocomplete`, and I get about 2.5 million results, I think all about the thing you are looking for. There are excellent examples in the jQuery docs, the first result you get! Use your brain please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it will help you you can take a look in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7392816/315935) which explain how to implement simple and more complex case of usage of jQuery UI Autocomplete inside of jqGrid. In the example will be used `dataInit` as `searchoptions` property. Absolutely the same property with the same code can be used inside of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions). The corresponding server code is in C#, but I hope you can understand it and implement the same in Java.

In [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FillToolbarSearchFilter.htm) from the "UPDATED" part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5329014/315935) you will find an example how jQuery UI Autocomplete will be used in the grid with pure local data.