# JQGrid filterToolbar is not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

This is the first time i'm working with the JQgrid. I've successfully loaded data to the Grid but my filterToolbar is not working. here is my view

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Index
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
 <title>jqGrid for ASP.NET MVC - Demo</title>
    <!-- The jQuery UI theme that will be used by the grid -->    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.0/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <!-- The Css UI theme extension of jqGrid -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />    
    <!-- jQuery library is a prerequisite for jqGrid -->
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- language pack - MUST be included before the jqGrid javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/trirand/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <!-- the jqGrid javascript runtime -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/trirand/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myGrid = $('#list');
        $(function () {
            $("#list").jqGrid({
                url: '/JqGridClients/DynamicGridData/',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',

                colNames: ['ClientID', 'Address', 'Company', 'Name'],
                colModel: [
          { name: 'ClientID', index: 'ClientID', search: false, width: 60, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', search: true, sortable: true, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Company', index: 'Company', search: true, align: 'left', stype: 'select' },
          { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', search: true, align: 'left', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn']}}],
                pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                sortname: 'ClientID',
                sortorder: "desc",
                viewrecords: true,
                imgpath: '/scripts/themes/coffee/images',
                caption: 'Clients',

            }).navGrid('#pager', { search: true, edit: false, add: false, del: false, searchtext: "Search" });

              $("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn' });
        });


    </script>  

    <h2>Index</h2>

<table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: have u got ny error in console??

Comment: @vishalsharma no errors in console

Comment: put navgrid call same as filtertoolbar

Comment: @vishalsharma hello! it working once i add the parameter  loadonce: true. but the "Name" column is not filtering it only works if i remove the searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn']} is there any issue with adding searchoptions?

Comment: You should specify `sopt` with the first `'eq'` operation only for columns having `stype: 'select'`. I recommend you additionally use `ignoreCase: true` to have case insensitive filtering (it works only is you use `loadonce: true` additionally) and add `sorttype: "integer"` for `'ClientID'` column. You should remove unneeded properties of `colModel` like `index: 'Address', search: true, sortable: true, align: 'left'` which values are *default* (see "Default" column of the table [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var myGrid = $('#list');
        $(function () {
            $("#list").jqGrid({
                url: '/JqGridClients/DynamicGridData/',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',

                colNames: ['ClientID', 'Address', 'Company', 'Name'],
                colModel: [
          { name: 'ClientID', index: 'ClientID', search: false, width: 60, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', search: true, sortable: true, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Company', index: 'Company', search: true, align: 'left', stype: 'select' },
          { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', search: true, sortable: true, align: 'left', searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn' ,'eq', 'ne']}}],
                pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                rowNum: 10,
                 width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                sortname: 'ClientID',
                sortorder: "desc",
                viewrecords: true,
                imgpath: '/scripts/themes/coffee/images',
                loadonce: true,
                caption: 'Clients',

            }).navGrid('#pager', { search: true, edit: false, add: false, del: false, searchtext: "Search" });

              $("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn' });

              $("#list").setGridParam({data: results.rows, localReader: reader}).trigger('reloadGrid');
        });


    </script>
```

I did few changes to the script and it's working fine now.

1. Add the parameter  loadonce: true
2. Changed the search options order in Name column

Answer (score 4):

You use correctly `filterToolbar`. You wrote just "my filterToolbar is not working" without any details. I suppose that you just not implemented filtering on the server side.

If the user enter filter in the filter toolbar new request will be send to the server (to `'/JqGridClients/DynamicGridData/'`). The option `filter` has format described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options). Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7392816/315935) for code examples.

If the number of rows in the grid which you need to display not so large (less as 1000 rows for example) then you can simplify your code by usage *client side paging and filtering*. You need just do make the following changes:

- add `loadonce: true` option to the grid
- change the server code so that you returns **all pages of data** (without paging on the server side) on request of jqGrid. You need still sort the data.

You should additionally review the option of jqGrid which you use. For example

- you use `imgpath` option which is [deprecated](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:upgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5#options) since jqGgrid 3.5 (the current version is 4.4.5).
- you need use `gridview: true` instead which improves performance
- you should replace `pager: jQuery('#pager')` to `pager: '#pager'` because jqGrid need *string* as parameter of jqGrid.
- you should reduce HTML fragment with `<table>` and `<div>` needed for jqGrid to `<table id="list" ></table><div id="pager"></div>`.  All other attributes (inclusive `class`) are deprecated and are not used in versions of jqGrid published last 3 years.