# Delete ID always 0 in Jqgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

JqGrid edit function is working fine in my grid but delete function always passes record id as 0.

```
@model Shop.Models.ShopModels.lstMainCategory
<table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
    <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>                                                            

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var myGrid = $('#list');
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.jgrid.nav.addtext = "Add";
            $.jgrid.nav.edittext = "Edit";
            $.jgrid.nav.deltext = "Delete";
            $.jgrid.edit.addCaption = "Add Main Category";
            $.jgrid.edit.closeAfterAdd = true;
            $.jgrid.edit.closeAfterEdit = true;
            $.jgrid.edit.editCaption = "Edit Main Category";
            $.jgrid.del.caption = "Delete Main Category";
            $.jgrid.del.msg = "Delete selected Main Category?";

            $.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
                beforeSubmit: function () {
                    $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json" });
                    return [true, "", ""];
                }
            });

            $("#list").jqGrid({
                url: '/MainCategory/DynamicGridData/',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',

                colNames: ['Edit', 'Main Category'],
                colModel: [
         { name: 'MaincategoryID', index: 'MaincategoryID', width: 40, align: 'left', /* key: true,*/editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: false }, hidedlg: true, hidden: true },
         { name: 'MainCategoryName', index: 'MainCategoryName', search: true, width: 700, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *'} }],
                pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                editurl: '@Url.Action("Update", "MainCategory")',
                rowNum: 10,
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                viewrecords: true,
                loadonce: true,
                ignoreCase: true,
                caption: 'Main Categories'

            }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true, searchtext: "Search" });

            $("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn' });

            $("#list").setGridParam({ data: results.rows, localReader: reader }).trigger('reloadGrid');


    </script>
```

**Controller:**

```
  public ActionResult Update(lstMainCategory viewModel, FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            var operation = formCollection["oper"];
            lstMainCategory mcat = new lstMainCategory();
            rep = new MaincategoryRepository();
            if (operation.Equals("add"))
            {              

                mcat.MainCategoryName = viewModel.MainCategoryName;
                rep.Create(mcat);
                rep.Save();
            }
            else if (operation.Equals("edit"))
            {
                mcat.MaincategoryID = viewModel.MaincategoryID;
                mcat.MainCategoryName = viewModel.MainCategoryName;
                rep.Edit(mcat);
                rep.Save();
            }
            else if (operation.Equals("del"))
            {

                rep.Delete(viewModel.MaincategoryID);//here MaincategoryID is always 0 so it's not working
                rep.Save();
            }

            return Content("true");
        }
```

**EDIT**

```
MainCategoryID  MainCategory
16           aaa
17           bbb
```

[image]

**Repository:**

```
 public object DynamicGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, bool _search, string searchField, string searchOper, string searchString)
        {

            dc = new ShopDataContext(DBConnection.Connection);

            int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
            int pageSize = rows;
            int totalRecords = dc.tblMainCategories.Count();
            int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

            List<MainCategory> lst = (from tbm in dc.tblMainCategories
                                select new MainCategory
                                {
                                    MaincategoryID=tbm.MainCategoryID,
                                    MainCategoryName=tbm.MainCategory,
                                    DeleteID=tbm.MainCategoryID
                                }).ToList<MainCategory>().OrderBy(x=>x.MainCategoryName).ToList();

            List<MainCategory> Flst;



            if (_search && searchField == "MainCategory")
            {
                Flst = lst.Where(r => r.MainCategoryName.Contains(searchString)).OrderBy(x => x.MainCategoryName).ToList().ToList();
            }
            else
                Flst = lst;


            var GridData = new
            {
                total = totalPages,
                page = page,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = (
                    from mcat in Flst
                    select new
                    {
                        i = mcat.MaincategoryID,
                        cell = new string[] { mcat.MaincategoryID.ToString(), mcat.MainCategoryName.ToString(),mcat.DeleteID.ToString() }
                    }).ToArray()
            };

            return GridData;
        }
```

Comment: Which data you use to fill the grid? Could you post two rows of data? Do you want to show contain of `MaincategoryID` to the user? Which value have `id` for the grid?

Comment: important is the **exact JSON response** returned from `'/MainCategory/DynamicGridData/'`. Table with dummy values gives no additional information. What you use as `id` (rowid)?

Comment: @Oleg MaincategoryID is the ID i want to pass at delete Action in my controller and i don't want to show it to the user. I have added two rows of data

Comment: Could you include exact JSON response returned from '/MainCategory/DynamicGridData/'? You can use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler), Firebug or Developer Tools of IE to catch HTTP traffic. I repeat my previous question: Do you want to show contain of MaincategoryID to the user?

Comment: The code from your previous answer (`var jsonData = rep.DynamicGridData(sidx, sord, page, rows, _search, searchField, searchOper, searchString);`) gives **no information about the format of data which you use** in the server response.

Comment: @Oleg please see the edit.i guess that's what you asked for?

Comment: One can see `i` property in the response. What is that? Is it has the same value as `MaincategoryID`? I repeat the third time my previous questions which are unanswered: **Do you want to show contain of MaincategoryID column to the user or not?**

Comment: @Oleg I have posted my repository method.you can see the i property there and for your next question "Do you want to show contain of MaincategoryID column to the user or not?" i don't want to show contain of MaincategoryID column to the user

Comment: I know the bug in the code from http://haacked.com/ where `i` was used instead of `id`. I send Phil Haack about it and he fixed the code on [the HTML page](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx), but one wrote my later that Phil don't makes the fix in the code available per download.

Comment: @Oleg oh! Thanks and got it working with id.I would have never figured it out without you'r help.Can you please post it as a answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should fix the format of server response which you use. It has **no `i` property, but it has `id` property instead**. The line

```
i = mcat.MaincategoryID,
```

have to be fixed to

```cs
id = mcat.MaincategoryID,
```

You can replace the code

```cs
rows = (
    from mcat in Flst
    select new
    {
        i = mcat.MaincategoryID,
        cell = new string[] { mcat.MaincategoryID.ToString(), mcat.MainCategoryName.ToString(),mcat.DeleteID.ToString() }
    }).ToArray()
```

to

```cs
rows = (
    from mcat in Flst
    select new[] {
        mcat.MaincategoryID.ToString(),
        mcat.MainCategoryName,
        mcat.DeleteID.ToString()
    }).ToArray()
```

to have no duplicated of the same information (sending `mcat.MaincategoryID` twice) and removing `"id:"` and `"cell:"` strings from every item which you send. To read such more compact data on the client side you should add `jsonReader: { cell: "" }` option to jqGrid. The option is optional if you use last version of jqGrid.

If you want that contain of `MaincategoryID` column will be send you should use `editrules: { edithidden: true }` option in the `MaincategoryID` column (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9128231/315935)). Alternatively you can add `prmNames: {id: "MaincategoryID"}`. In the case jqGrid will send rowid as "MaincategoryID" instead of default value `"id"`.

If you don't need to display `MaincategoryID` column then you can **remove it from `colModel`**. In the case you could change the order of data returned from the server to

```cs
rows = (
    from mcat in Flst
    select new[] {
        mcat.MainCategoryName,
        mcat.MaincategoryID.ToString(),
        mcat.DeleteID.ToString()
    }).ToArray()
```

The changed in jqGrid will be

```
colNames: ['Edit', 'Main Category'],
colModel: [
    { name: 'MainCategoryName', width: 700, editable: true,
        editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *'} }
],
pager: "#pager",
gridview: true,
jsonReader: {cell: "", id: 1},
prmNames: {id: "MaincategoryID"}
```

jqGrid assign `id` attribute to every row (every `<tr>`). Using `sonReader: {id: 1}` one inform jqGrid to get the rowid from the second item of the row data (`mcat.MaincategoryID.ToString()`). Other changes `pager: "#pager"` and `gridview: true` are the same what I wrote you before in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16515324/315935). You should remove additionally garbage from `<table id="list" ...` and `<div id="paber" ...` (see my old answer)